# Java Regex Groups within groups

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I'm struggling with regex since an hour now. So, just below this is my text I want to parse.

```
AddAgenda("Gangster's agenda", 
{ 
    TEAM_HITMAN, 
    TEAM_POLICE
}, 
{   
    TEAM_GANG,
    TEAM_MAFIA,
    TEAM_GANGSTER
})
```

I would like to capture the agenda name, each team ***INDIVUDUALLY*** from each pair of curly braces. One thing to know is that I don't know how much teams there are within with each of these pairs.

Basically, I want this:

```
Group [1]:
    Gangster's agenda
Group [2]:
    Group [0]: TEAM_HITMAN
    Group [1]: TEAM_POLICE
Group [3]:
    Group [0]: TEAM_GANG
    Group [1]: TEAM_MAFIA
    Group [2]: TEAM_GANGSTER
```

But I've only came up with this:

```
AddAgenda\(\"([^"]+)\",\s*\{(\s*([\w_]+,))*
```

Which produces this:

```
Group [0]:
    [0]: AddAgenda("Gangster's agenda", 
{ 
    TEAM_MOB, 
    TEAM_POLICE,
Group [1]:
    [0]: Gangster's agenda
Group [2]:
   [0]:  
    TEAM_POLICE,
Group [3]:
    [0]: TEAM_POLICE,
```

Comment: Just write a _parser_ that reads each piece of the input and extracts the wanted values.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: I have never ever ever ever understood the fascination with doing things like this with a regex. Just write the code you want to parse the text. Why make it unnecessarily complicated and illegible?

Comment: @nhouser9 I think the problem is that people find out about regex, and then assume that it is the only tool to process text. Y'know, [everything looks like a nail](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument).

Comment: In a certain manner it's just curiosity. I would like to know if it's possible to achieve this with just one regex expression.

Answer (score 1):

[This my try](https://regex101.com/r/Qq2muv/1):

```
AddAgenda\(\"([^"]+)\",\s*\{(\s*([\w_]+)\s*,?\s*([\w_]+)\s*)},\s*{\s*(([\w_]+)\s*,?\s*([\w_]+)?\s*,?\s*([\w_]+)?)\s*}\s*\)
```

So looking at your question, group 3,4 are contained by group 2, group 6,7,8 (TEAM_GANG, TEAM_MAFIA, TEAM_GANGSTER) are contained by Group 5.

The problem we have using only one regex is that you can't generate a new capture group automatically for each TEAM. To be clear, one features of regular expressions is that you can apply quantifiers to patterns. \d+ eats up more digits. For instance, the regex (\d) captures a digit into group 1.

So what happens if you put the two together into this regex?

`(\d)+`

The capturing parentheses you see in a pattern only capture a single group. So in (\d)+, capture groups do not proceed repeating the match again. The regex repeatedly refer again to the same group. If you try `(\d)+` regex on 1234, Group 1 will contain `4`, the last capture.

In a nut shell, Group 1 has been overwritten every time the regex iterates through the capturing parentheses.

Using two regex you could divide the problem in two parts. First match the three parameters in `AddAgenda`. Then split the two parameters in curly braces.

[First regular](https://regex101.com/r/hq8ON5/1) expression could be:

```
AddAgenda\("([^"]+)",\s*\{\s*([^}]+)\},\s*\{\s*([^}]+)\s*\}\)
```

[Second regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/hq8ON5/2) very simple.

```
([\w_]+)
```

In this case, in java you could execute the following code:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[\\w_]+").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I add/delete a team your regex does not work anymore.

Comment: I've updated my answer, this version works handle the missing teams.

Comment: Still didn't work as expected, nvm I'll just use 2 regex expressions instead.

Comment: I've update again my answer, this version explain why you can't have repeating capture groups in the same regular expression.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
\"(.*)\"|\s([A-Z_].*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/6vJpXe/1

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is that I can't distinguish from which groups each team belongs to.